# Contextual filter + exposed filter

Tags: views

My view have following "EXPOSED" filters with Industry. And Contextual filter of Taxonomy.  So when I do asia/agriculture. %1 should be Asia and it's coming along fine. But %2 should go to Exposed Filter and it should filter out all the nodes with "agricultural" term.

Is it possible in Drupal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Views Filter Harmonizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_harmonizer) module. It allows you to have a contextual filter argument apply only when there is no corresponding regular (exposed) filter value present.

Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> Views Filter Harmonizer solves an operational foible with the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)
>   module regarding filtering.
>   Normally, when a Views field has been assigned both an [exposed](http://drupal.org/node/1578534) filter
>   and a [contextual](http://drupal.org/node/1578558) filter, then both filters get applied to the View's
>   results set -- **always**. This is not configurable behaviour. It's
>   hard-coded.
>
> As a consequence, contradictory search clauses easily occur, causing a
>   counter-intuitive user experience with some White Screens of
>   Disillusionment. Since the contextual filter sets the "bounds" for the
>   page, any filtering by the visitor through the exposed filter on that
>   page can only narrow down the results set, not broaden it. In other
>   words the exposed filter appears not to be working properly.
>
> This small module allows you to have a contextual filter argument
>   apply only when there is no corresponding regular (exposed) filter
>   value present.
>
> This is most common on initial page load. After that the contextual
>   filters will silently retreat and let the exposed filter values as
>   selected by the visitor do their thing without interfering.
>
> This means that you can take advantage of friendly URLs using
>   contextual arguments instead of ugly and verbose query parameters. Put
>   the URLs anywhere on your site, in emails and in newsletters to take
>   visitors to tailored Views pages. Having arrived there, visitors may
>   then further filter these pages to their heart's content using the
>   View's regular filters you exposed. And they won't experience any odd
>   behaviour.